# RoR Adding pagination with Kaminari

Tags: ruby-on-rails, kaminari

I wanted to add some pagination to my rails project. 
I've already added `Kaminari` and I've managed to display only 10 records per page. But I'm already missing the next/prev arrow and the page indicator.

I'm using `Kaminari.paginate_array(@array).page(params[:page]).per(10)`

This is the only thing I've added until now.

I don't know if it's important, but in my view I have `@array.to_json`

What should I add to display the arrows?

View code:

```
<% content_for :create_button do %>
  <%= create_button(new_battery_reset_path) %>
<% end %>
<div class="tab-content">
  <%= paginate @battery_resets %>
  <div class="tab-pane active" id="battery-resets" role="tabpanel"
    data-battery-resets='<%= @battery_resets.to_json %>'>
  </div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="profile" role="tabpanel">...</div>
  <div class="tab-pane" id="messages" role="tabpanel">...</div>
</div>
```

controller code:

```
def index
    @battery_resets = Kaminari.paginate_array(BatteryResetDecorator.build_collection(
      ::Filters::BatteryReset.new(
          current_account.battery_resets.includes({ device: :account },
            :device_inspection)
      ).apply(permited_params[:q])
    )).page(params[:page]).per(10)

    respond_with(@battery_resets)
  end
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per the [docs](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari#views):

> Just call the paginate helper:
>
> ```
> <%= paginate @battery_resets %>
> ```
>
> This will render several `?page=N` pagination links surrounded by an
>   HTML5 `<nav>` tag.

This is the same pattern for [`will_paginate`](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) (another gem) also.

--

In regards your `fa_icon` error, that's caused by the [`font-awesome-rails`](https://github.com/bokmann/font-awesome-rails) gem; it means the helper is not available.

The way to fix it is to make sure you're only using the bundled files with `Kaminari`. If you've changed `_next_page.html.erb` in any way, the error is likely coming back now.

--

The quick fix for the `fa_icon` error is to add `font-awesome-rails` to your `Gemfile`:

```
#Gemfile
gem "font-awesome-rails"
```

Comment: i didn't know that file existed so i believe is intact.

Comment: Do you use the `font-awesome-rails` gem anywhere in your app?

Comment: It shouldn't need it - this is probably what the issue is (maybe Kaminari is using it, let me check).

Comment: Looks like Kaminari doesn't use it. Can you post a screenshot of your error in your question for me to check?

Comment: I've just looked through the [Kaminari code](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari/blob/master/app/views/kaminari/_paginator.html.erb#L9) and it doesn't have this. Which gem are you using? just `gem kaminari`?

Comment: The simple fix is to include `gem "font-awesome-rails"` in your `Gemfile` for now; we'll see if it resolves the issue.

Comment: it solved it! thanks!! if you post it as a question i will accept it

Comment: Nice work, it would be interesting to see what caused it though. I updated the answer

Answer (score 1):

You might want to put `<%= paginate @array %>` in your rails view.
Also try to read gem's wiki first before asking any questions.( [kaminari wiki](https://github.com/amatsuda/kaminari) )

Comment: Hey, easy! That wouldn't do it. That's why i'm asking. if i add that i get a font awesome error. And if i do paginate @array.to_json i get a no method current_page error

Comment: there you go. Sorry for the messy code. that's why i simplyfied with @array

Comment: Could you also paste that 'font awesome' error which you mentioned above?

Comment: undefined method `fa_icon' for #<#<Class:0x007fa9758124c0>:0x007fa975810d00>

Comment: Showing /Users/maite/workspace/device-mgmt/app/views/kaminari/_next_page.html.erb where line #11 raised:

Comment: could it has something to do with the fact that is a nested resource?